# What is mean by reference in .net wrt CLR (managing objects)?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, reference, clr

What is mean by reference in .net wrt CLR (managing objects)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to think in terms of C++ pointers, then it means that if you pass an object to a method by reference, then the method can modify the original object.  If you pass it by value, then the method gets a copy of the object and can't modify the original.

Answer (score 1):

That means only pointer to an object is passed, not the whole object...